# База данных неверно отражает данные по user_id

Tags: sql, jsp, servlet

***Доброго времени суток. Прошу помочь разобраться в вопросе правильно ли работает БД и приложение. У меня мало опыта в этом. Благодарю, за уделенное время.***

***У меня есть 2 таблицы users и их meals, которые связаны foreign key user_id***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meals;

CREATE TABLE meals
(
    id               INTEGER             GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id          INTEGER                           NOT NULL,
    date_time        TIMESTAMP           DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    description      VARCHAR                           NOT NULL,
    calories         INTEGER             DEFAULT 1000  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX meals_unique_datetime_isx ON meals (date_time);

insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100000, '2020-12-19 10:07:04', 'Breakfast', 416);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100001, '2021-07-11 06:51:10', 'Breakfast', 2128);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100000, '2020-11-12 05:31:33', 'Afternoon snack', 1084);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100000, '2021-04-15 07:37:50', 'Afternoon snack', 1907);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100000, '2021-03-12 10:28:08', 'Breakfast', 637);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100001, '2021-04-27 17:25:54', 'Lunch', 1021);
insert into meals (user_id, date_time, description, calories) values (100001, '2020-11-06 20:52:52', 'Afternoon snack', 1016);
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_roles;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS global_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE global_seq START WITH 100000;
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id               INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('global_seq'),
    name             VARCHAR                           NOT NULL,
    email            VARCHAR                           NOT NULL,
    password         VARCHAR                           NOT NULL,
    registered       TIMESTAMP           DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    enabled          BOOL                DEFAULT TRUE  NOT NULL,
    calories_per_day INTEGER             DEFAULT 2000  NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_unique_email_idx ON users (email);

CREATE TABLE user_roles
(
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    role    VARCHAR,
    CONSTRAINT user_roles_idx UNIQUE (user_id, role),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

***На главной странице есть выбор пользователя - вот фрагмент этой html страницы***

```
<form method="post" action="users">
    <b style="font-size: large">Meals of&nbsp;</b>
    <select name="userId">
        <option value="100000">User</option>
        <option value="100001">Admin</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Select</button>
</form>
```

***Но когда я выбираю user у меня выводится список для admin, а для admin`a наоборот userские meals. Интересует, почему это происходит?
В Сервлет приходит пост-запрос с парметром userId, который сетится в SecurutyUtil***

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
        SecurityUtil.setAuthUserId(userId);
        response.sendRedirect("meals");
    }
```

```
public class SecurityUtil {

    private static int id = AbstractBaseEntity.START_SEQ;

    public static int authUserId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static void setAuthUserId(int id) {
        SecurityUtil.id = id;
    }
```

***По умолчанию в AbstractBaseEntity id обычного User`a***

```
public static final int START_SEQ = 100000;
```

Comment: Если программа составлена верно, то так происходит из-за того, что данные в бд такие. т.е. в таблице одна запись `users id=100000 name=admin`, другая `id=100001 name=user`. Вы бы написало запросы `insert into users`... А лучше вывод `select id, name from users where id in (100000, 100001)`

Comment: решилось . запрос был составлен не верно
 List<Meal> getAll(int id) {
return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM meals WHERE user_id=? ORDER BY user_id, date_time DESC", ROW_MAPPER, userId);
} так верно
    }